# Separete trackbacks/pings and numbered comments

Tags: comments, pingbacks

I've been googling around for tutorials of how to 
a) number the comments in the comment list and
b) seperate trackbacks/pings from the rest of your comments.

All the tutorials seem to be out of date?! They all suggest you look for something in your comment.php file that I haven't seen in any newer theme lately, namely:

```
<?php if ( $comments ) : ?>
```

or

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
```

I don't seem to have anything like that in my comment.php.
I also checked the comment.template and comment.php in the wp-includes folder, but couldn't find anything.
Also no luck looking through the function.php.

Here's the comment-related snipped of my function.php:

```
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class('clearfix'); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
 <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='63'); ?>
 <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata clearfix">
    <?php printf(__('<strong>%s</strong>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('<img src="http://www.zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/themes/alltuts/images/edit.gif">'),'  ','') ?> <span><?php printf(__('%1$s @ %2$s'), get_comment_date('Y/n/j'),  get_comment_time('G:i')) ?>
  </span>
 <div class="text">
      <?php comment_text() ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
     <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
     <br />
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="reply">
     <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And here's my comment.php: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CdkBFNN5)

I'd really appreciate your advice.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numbering, in your comment.php, change this:

```
wp_list_comments('callback=mytheme_comment');
```

To this:

```
wp_list_comments(array(
  'callback'=>'mytheme_comment',
  'style'=>'ol',
));
```

For separation into comments and pingbacks, you'd do something like this:

```
wp_list_comments(array(
  'callback'=>'mytheme_comment',
  'style'=>'ol',
  'type'=>'comment',
));

wp_list_comments(array(
  'callback'=>'mytheme_comment',
  'style'=>'ol',
  'type'=>'pings',
));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Now the pingbacks are seperate :) However, the comments still don't seem to be numbered. Do I have to add anything in addition to that? (You can also check it live at my website: zoomingjapan dot com Thanks again! :)

Comment: You'll need to use CSS to make it display the numbering.

Comment: I tried the following code snippet to seperate pingbacks and comments because I wanted to have a headline for the Pingbacks: wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/… It didn't work, instead no comments/pingbacks at all showed up. With the code you provided, what do I have to do to get the comment numbers to show up, I tried ".commentnumber" but no effect, so I guess I have to create some divs for that first? Where would I put those, though?! Thanks again!